# removing google-gax from next js browser code

Tags: firebase, webpack, safari, next.js

I have a next.js setup with firebase-admin to be used on server side. But I can't run the page on safari due to following error. (no problem with chrome)

> SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name

on a regex

> /(?<={)[$0-9a-zA-Z_]+(?==.*})/g

which is from googel-gax(google-gax/build/src/pathTemplate.js) which is a dependency of firebase-admin.

My question is how to avoid firebase-admin from being loaded into the browser?

Following is my next.config.js

```
module.exports = (phase, {defaultConfig, isServer}) => {
    return {
        ...defaultConfig,
        // experimental: {
        //     granularChunks: true,
        // },
        /* config options here */
        webpack: (config, options) => {
            config.node = {
                // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
                // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
                ...config.node,
                fs: 'empty',
                child_process: 'empty',
                net: 'empty',
                tls: 'empty',
                worker_threads: 'empty',
                request: 'empty',
                "fast-crc32c": 'empty',
                "firebase-admin": 'empty',
                "google-gax": 'empty'
            };
            return config
        },
        distDir: 'build',
    };
}
```

Following is the firebase admin usage

```
let admin = null;
if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    admin = require('firebase-admin');
    if (!admin.apps.length) {
        console.log("initializing firebase...");
        let serviceAccount = {};
        serviceAccount = require('../../keys/firebase-key.json');
        admin.initializeApp({
            credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
            storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
            databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
        });
    }
}

export {admin as firebaseAdmin};
```

Comment: This was answered here. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/18187

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out the issue. some paths were calling firebaseAdmin calls for server side rendering to ignore fetch() calls. Now it's working.

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        let ref = firebaseClient.storage().ref(path);
        return await ref.getDownloadURL() as string;
    } else {

        // before change
        const admin = require('firebase-admin');
        let bucket = admin.storage().bucket(process.env.NEXT_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET);

        // after change
        let bucket = firebaseAdmin.storage().bucket(process.env.NEXT_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET);
        let file = bucket.file(path);

        return file.getSignedUrl({
            action: 'read',
            expires: '03-17-2025'
        })
            .then((data: GetSignedUrlResponse) => {
                return data[0];
            });
    }
```